# Using dplyr to add summary rows

Tags: r, dplyr

```
       Gender Year.10 Year.11 Year.12 Year.13 Year.10.1 Year.11.1 Year.12.1 Year.13.1
1      FEMALE 1181980 1113480 1040960 1033150   1116220   1059850   1022950    974490
2        MALE  674020  783150  571170  594330    641620    767590    554290    563670
3 UNSPECIFIED   31930    7740   14670   17420     31930      5590      9170     17420
```

I have summed up my data and want to add these sums to underneath their respective Genders in my data.frame. So for instance after my female rows, I want to add my female sums underneath it (with Age == "All")
I think I can accomplish this using dplyr, but I don't know how to select positions in the data.frame.

I think it would have to be something along the lines of:

```
dummy.c %>%
group_by(Gender) %>%
rowwise () %>%
mutate () #### It's here where I don't know where to go on from
```

I used `summarise_each(funs(sum=sum(., na.rm=TRUE)), starts_with("Year"))` to generate my summary, I probably have to put that in my mutate ().

```
> dput(dummy.c[sample(1:nrow(dummy.c), 15, replace=FALSE),])
structure(list(Gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("FEMALE", "MALE", 
"UNSPECIFIED"), class = "factor"), Age = structure(c(5L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("0-2", 
"3-9", "10-19", "20-39", "40-59", "60-64", "65+", "UNSP"), class = "factor"), 
Year.10 = c(484770L, 58440L, 58570L, 200290L, NA, 54780L, 
238600L, NA, 2470L, 10920L, 46890L, 63360L, 16900L, 12850L, 
NA), Year.11 = c(439860L, 92870L, 60060L, 264280L, NA, 54400L, 
258820L, NA, NA, NA, 30150L, 84750L, 22380L, NA, 2150L), 
Year.12 = c(454200L, 50900L, 55600L, 230460L, 3610L, 47960L, 
148530L, NA, NA, 5500L, 18020L, 64810L, 2260L, 5560L, NA), 
Year.13 = c(412650L, 84110L, 38000L, 205600L, NA, 40600L, 
185770L, 5670L, NA, 5700L, 19060L, 79150L, 5860L, NA, NA), 
Gender.1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("FEMALE", "MALE", "UNSPECIFIED"
), class = "factor"), Age.1 = structure(c(5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("0-2", 
"3-9", "10-19", "20-39", "40-59", "60-64", "65+", "UNSP"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), Year.10.1 = c(460340L, 52680L, 58570L, 197110L, 
NA, 54780L, 226110L, NA, 2470L, 10920L, 41370L, 52240L, 16900L, 
12850L, NA), Year.11.1 = c(417800L, 87280L, 60060L, 264280L, 
NA, 54400L, 248810L, NA, NA, NA, 30150L, 79200L, 22380L, 
NA, NA), Year.12.1 = c(447400L, 50900L, 50100L, 224700L, 
3610L, 47960L, 148530L, NA, NA, NA, 18020L, 59190L, 2260L, 
5560L, NA), Year.13.1 = c(395700L, 78440L, 36520L, 200050L, 
NA, 37360L, 185770L, 5670L, NA, 5700L, 19060L, 62130L, 5860L, 
NA, NA)), .Names = c("Gender", "Age", "Year.10", "Year.11", 
"Year.12", "Year.13", "Gender.1", "Age.1", "Year.10.1", "Year.11.1", 
"Year.12.1", "Year.13.1"), row.names = c(5L, 3L, 11L, 12L, 22L, 
14L, 13L, 16L, 21L, 23L, 2L, 15L, 9L, 20L, 17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Edit 1: To show data

`> head(dummy.c)`

```
  Gender   Age Year.10 Year.11 Year.12 Year.13 Gender.1 Age.1 Year.10.1 Year.11.1 Year.12.1 Year.13.1
1 FEMALE   0-2   13700    2470    7820    2100   FEMALE   0-2     13700      2470      7820      2100
2 FEMALE   3-9   46890   30150   18020   19060   FEMALE   3-9     41370     30150     18020     19060
3 FEMALE 10-19   58440   92870   50900   84110   FEMALE 10-19     52680     87280     50900     78440
4 FEMALE 20-39  380610  387080  291930  371290   FEMALE 20-39    356070    372370    280720    356500
5 FEMALE 40-59  484770  439860  454200  412650   FEMALE 40-59    460340    417800    447400    395700
6 FEMALE 60-64   80090   76670   92750   60710   FEMALE 60-64     80090     76670     92750     49240`
```

`tail(dummy.c)`

```
        Gender   Age Year.10 Year.11 Year.12 Year.13    Gender.1 Age.1 Year.10.1 Year.11.1 Year.12.1
18 UNSPECIFIED 10-19    5690      NA      NA      NA UNSPECIFIED 10-19      5690        NA        NA
19 UNSPECIFIED 20-39      NA    5590      NA   11720 UNSPECIFIED 20-39        NA      5590        NA
20 UNSPECIFIED 40-59   12850      NA    5560      NA UNSPECIFIED 40-59     12850        NA      5560
21 UNSPECIFIED 60-64    2470      NA      NA      NA UNSPECIFIED 60-64      2470        NA        NA
22 UNSPECIFIED   65+      NA      NA    3610      NA UNSPECIFIED   65+        NA        NA      3610
23 UNSPECIFIED  UNSP   10920      NA    5500    5700 UNSPECIFIED  UNSP     10920        NA        NA
   Year.13.1
18        NA
19     11720
20        NA
21        NA
22        NA
23      5700
```

Comment: It is unclear how would your desired output will look like as your data isn't sorted by gender, nor it has the same amount of columns like your summed up data has

Comment: Sorry for not putting example data, and my poor explanation of what I want the output to be. So for instance after my female rows, I want to add my female sums underneath it (with Age == "All")

Comment: I'd recommend reading my paper on tidy data: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v59/i10. You'll get much more out of tidyr and dplyr if you understand the underlying principles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative using `reshape2` and `dplyr` packages (both of the same author, btw=P):

```
df <- structure(...) # structure of your question
```

Now, melt and cast:

```
df %>% 
  select(-Gender.1,-Age.1) %>% 
  melt %>% # melting data.frame. See the results until here to better understanding.
  dcast(Gender + Age ~ variable, sum, na.rm=TRUE, margins = "Age")
```

What's going on, line by line:

1. your data.frame
2. removing duplicated columns
3. melting data.frame. See the results until here to better understanding.
4. aggregate by `Gender`, `Age` and `variable` (Years, in this case). The aggregation function is `sum` with na.rm=TRUE. Then, `margin = "Age"` puts the totals by `Age`, as desired.

Results:

```
        Gender   Age Year.10 Year.11 Year.12 Year.13 Year.10.1 Year.11.1 Year.12.1 Year.13.1
1       FEMALE   3-9   46890   30150   18020   19060     41370     30150     18020     19060
2       FEMALE 10-19   58440   92870   50900   84110     52680     87280     50900     78440
3       FEMALE 40-59  484770  439860  454200  412650    460340    417800    447400    395700
4       FEMALE (all)  590100  562880  523120  515820    554390    535230    516320    493200
5         MALE   0-2   16900   22380    2260    5860     16900     22380      2260      5860
...
17 UNSPECIFIED  UNSP   10920       0    5500    5700     10920         0         0      5700
18 UNSPECIFIED (all)   26240    2150   14670    5700     26240         0      9170      5700
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this works perfectly. I'm definitely adding `reshape2` to my list of packages to learn!