# Add margin row totals in dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to add overall summary rows while also calculating summaries by group using dplyr. I have found various questions asking how to do this, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328336/using-dplyr-to-add-summary-rows), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033449/dplyr-pipe-how-to-add-a-margin-row-calculating-a-total-like-addmargins-functio), and [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/435), but no clear solution. One possible approach is to perform `count` twice and bind the rows:

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl, gear) %>% 
  bind_rows(
    count(mtcars, gear)
  )
```

which *nearly* produces what I need (the left-most column has NAs rather than 'Total' or similar):

```
     cyl  gear     n
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1      4     3     1
2      4     4     8
3      4     5     2
4      6     3     2
5      6     4     4
6      6     5     1
7      8     3    12
8      8     5     2
9     NA     3    15
10    NA     4    12
11    NA     5     5
```

Am I missing an easier/built-in solution?

Comment: you could just do `addmargins(table(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$gear))` in base R.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

With adorn_totals() from the janitor package:

```
library(janitor)
mtcars %>%
  tabyl(cyl, gear) %>%
  adorn_totals("row") 

   cyl  3  4 5
     4  1  8 2
     6  2  4 1
     8 12  0 2
 Total 15 12 5
```

To get from there to the "long" form in your post, add `tidyr::gather()` to the pipeline:

```
mtcars %>%
  tabyl(cyl, gear) %>%
  adorn_totals("row") %>%
  tidyr::gather(gear, n, 2:ncol(.), convert = TRUE)

     cyl gear  n
1      4    3  1
2      6    3  2
3      8    3 12
4  Total    3 15
5      4    4  8
6      6    4  4
7      8    4  0
8  Total    4 12
9      4    5  2
10     6    5  1
11     8    5  2
12 Total    5  5
```

*Self-promotion alert, I authored this package - adding this answer b/c it's a genuinely efficient solution here.*

Comment: Thanks for the additional method suggestion. I have recently started using janitor, mostly for clean_names(), excel_numeric_to_date() and remove_empty(), all of which are super helpful in my day-to-day work. I'll now add these functions too... Congratulations on a fantastic package!

Answer (score 14):

One option is with `do`

```
mtcars %>%
   count(cyl, gear) %>%
   ungroup() %>% 
   mutate(cyl=as.character(cyl)) %>% 
   do(bind_rows(., data.frame(cyl="Total", count(mtcars, gear)))) 
   #or replace the last 'do' step with 
   #bind_rows(cbind(cyl='Total', count(mtcars, gear))) #from  @JonnyPolonsky's comments

#      cyl  gear     n
#   <chr> <dbl> <int>
#1      4     3     1
#2      4     4     8
#3      4     5     2
#4      6     3     2
#5      6     4     4
#6      6     5     1
#7      8     3    12
#8      8     5     2
#9  Total     3    15
#10 Total     4    12
#11 Total     5     5
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, that works very well. I am not sure that the `do` call is necessary - `mtcars %>%
   count(cyl, gear) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   mutate(cyl=as.character(cyl)) %>%
   bind_rows(cbind(cyl='Total', count(mtcars, gear)))` works just as well. I will wait to see if anyone offers an in-built `dplyr` answer, and will accept in 24 hours of not. Many thanks

Comment: @JonnyPolonsky  Thanks, I am in a bus, so couldn't use the mouse.  Tht should work as well.

Comment: No need for the `ungroup().` `Count()` calls `group_by()` before and `ungroup()` after.

Comment: @Nettle I used `ungroup` because there is a `mutate` step which doesn't need `group_by` although it works with the group_by

Comment: @akrun RE: comment by @Jonny "I am not sure that the do call is necessary" - I have just realised that it is preferable to use `do()`. When creating the row margin you want to be able to refer to `.` so you can access the data as `mutate()`d by previous steps. It's usually not going to be possible to calculate the marginal statistics off the original data frame as was done in this simple example. `do()` provides this.

Comment: @MichaelHenry this is an old post.  Now, there are better ways to deal with this

Answer (score 12):

Here's a take on the accepted answer, using new functions introduced in dplyr 1.0.0 and tidyr 1.0.0.

We pivot the counts using the new `tidyr::pivot_wider`. Then use the new `dplyr::rowwise` and `dplyr::c_across` to sum the counts for the total column.

We can also use `tidyr::pivot_longer` to get in desired long format.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

cyl_gear_sum <- mtcars %>%
  count(cyl, gear) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = gear, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  rowwise(cyl) %>%
  mutate(gear_total = sum(c_across()))

cyl_gear_sum
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#> # Rowwise:  cyl
#>     cyl   `3`   `4`   `5` gear_total
#>   <dbl> <int> <int> <int>      <int>
#> 1     4     1     8     2         11
#> 2     6     2     4     1          7
#> 3     8    12     0     2         14

# total as row
cyl_gear_sum %>% 
  pivot_longer(-cyl, names_to = "gear", values_to = "n")
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>      cyl gear           n
#>    <dbl> <chr>      <int>
#>  1     4 3              1
#>  2     4 4              8
#>  3     4 5              2
#>  4     4 gear_total    11
#>  5     6 3              2
#>  6     6 4              4
#>  7     6 5              1
#>  8     6 gear_total     7
#>  9     8 3             12
#> 10     8 4              0
#> 11     8 5              2
#> 12     8 gear_total    14
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 11):

An addition to @arkrun's answer that is not easy to add as a comment:

Although a little more complex, this format allows for previous modifications in the data frame. Useful when there is a longer chain of verbs before the table is generated. (You want to change names, or select only specific variables)

```
mtcars %>%
   count(cyl, gear) %>%
   ungroup() %>% 
   mutate(cyl=as.character(cyl))
bind_rows(group_by(.,gear) %>%
              summarise(n=sum(n)) %>%
              mutate(cyl='Total')) %>%
spread(cyl)

## A tibble: 3 x 5
#   gear   `4`   `6`   `8` Total
#* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     3     1     2    12    15
#2     4     8     4     0    12
#3     5     2     1     2     5
```

This can also be doubled up to generate a total row for the spread as well.

```
mtcars %>%
  count(cyl, gear) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(cyl=as.character(cyl),
         gear = as.character(gear)) %>%
  bind_rows(group_by(.,gear) %>%
              summarise(n=sum(n)) %>%
              mutate(cyl='Total')) %>%
  bind_rows(group_by(.,cyl) %>%
              summarise(n=sum(n)) %>%
              mutate(gear='Total')) %>%
  spread(cyl,n,fill=0)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
   gear   `4`   `6`   `8` Total
* <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     1     2    12    15
2     4     8     4     0    12
3     5     2     1     2     5
4 Total    11     7    14    32
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have truly universal solution you could use a combination of purrr::map_df, base::c and base::sum

`mtcars %>%
  purrr::map_df(~c(.x, sum(.x, na.rm=TRUE))) %>%
  tail`

P.S. All columns must be numeric!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

#Pre-process mtcars 
mtcars_pre <-
  as_tibble(mtcars) %>% #remove rownames
  select(cyl, gear) %>% 
  count(cyl, gear) %>% #add row totals
  mutate(
    cyl = as.character(cyl) #Convert to character in order to add "Total"
  )

#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   cyl    gear     n
#>   <chr> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 4         3     1
#> 2 4         4     8
#> 3 4         5     2
#> 4 6         3     2
#> 5 6         4     4
#> 6 6         5     1
#> 7 8         3    12
#> 8 8         5     2

mtcars_totals <- 
  mtcars_pre %>%
  bind_rows(
    mtcars_pre %>%
      group_by(gear) %>%
      summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
      mutate("cyl" = "Total")
  ) %>% 
  arrange(
    gear
  )

#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#>    cyl    gear     n
#>    <chr> <dbl> <int>
#>  1 4         3     1
#>  2 6         3     2
#>  3 8         3    12
#>  4 Total     3    15
#>  5 4         4     8
#>  6 6         4     4
#>  7 Total     4    12
#>  8 4         5     2
#>  9 6         5     1
#> 10 8         5     2
#> 11 Total     5     5
```

Created on 2021-07-13 by the reprex package (v2.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

Modified jlao's code a bit:

```
mtcars %>%
  # convert cyl column as.character
  mutate_at("cyl",as.character) %>%
  # add a copy of the original data with cyl column = 'TOTAL'
  bind_rows(mutate(mtcars, cyl="total")) %>%
  count(cyl,gear)
```

Comment: Nice and simple, though I would recommend swapping the superseded *mutate_at* for *mutate(across(cyl, as.character))*

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion.

1. Find the combination of relevant grouping variables via the powerSet function.
2. split the data frame into a list, grouped by the powerSet of the grouping variables
3. summarise the data frame using an appropriate summary function (e.g. mean)
4. bind_rows the result - summaries are now NA because these columns are dropped in step 3
5. replace NA values of the grouping variables using appropriate names.

Note. If grouping variables are numeric, they will not be dropped in step 3 - I therefore mutate them to character variables.

```
powerSetList <- function(df, ...) {
  rje::powerSet(x = c(...))[-1] %>% lapply(function(x, tdf = df) group_by(tdf, .dots=x)) %>% c(list(tibble(df)), .)
} 

mtcars %>% 
  mutate_at(vars("cyl", "gear"), as.character) %>%
  powerSetList("cyl", "gear") %>%
  map(~summarise_if(., is.numeric, .funs = mean)) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  replace_na(list(gear = "all gears",
                  cyl = "all cyls"))
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe that works:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    # convert cyl column as.character
    mutate_at("cyl",as.character) %>%
    # add a copy of the origina data with cyl column = 'TOTAL'
    bind_rows(mutate(mtcars, cyl="total")) %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>% summarise_all(sum)
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution, but I think it does not fully address the nested grouping the original asker is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since `summarize()` unpacks data frame arguments, such as the output of `across()`, we can build our own data.frame with the code below.

```r
library(dplyr, w = F)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize(
    bind_rows(
      summarize(group_by(across(everything()), gear), n =  n()),
      tibble(gear = NA, n =  n()),
    ),
    .groups = "drop",
  )
#> # A tibble: 11 × 3
#>      cyl  gear     n
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1     4     3     1
#>  2     4     4     8
#>  3     4     5     2
#>  4     4    NA    11
#>  5     6     3     2
#>  6     6     4     4
#>  7     6     5     1
#>  8     6    NA     7
#>  9     8     3    12
#> 10     8     5     2
#> 11     8    NA    14
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Here's a tidyverse style function to do it painlessly :

```r
#' Summarize with margins
#'
#' @inheritParams dplyr::summarize 
#' @param .by list of quosures, usually built with `quos()`
#' @param .all value to use for variables that are not part of the group.
#'   can be a named list using grouping column names.
#'
#' @return
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' mtcars %>% 
#'  summarize_with_margins(n =  n(), .by = quos(cyl, c(gear, cyl)))
#' mtcars %>% 
#'  summarize_with_margins(n =  n(), .by = quos(cyl, c(gear, cyl)), .all = Inf)
#' mtcars %>% 
#'  summarize_with_margins(n =  n(), .by = quos(cyl, c(gear, cyl)), .all = list(gear = -1))
summarize_with_margins <- function(.data, ..., .by = NULL, .all = NA) {
  if (!rlang::is_quosures(.by)) {
    rlang::abort('`.by` should be a "quosures" object, use `quos()`.')
  }
  dfs <- purrr::map(.by, function(x) {
    .data %>% 
      group_by(across(!!x)) %>% 
      summarize(..., .groups = "drop")
  })
  all_nms <- unique(unlist(lapply(dfs, names)))
  purrr::map_dfr(dfs, ~{
    .x <- rev(.x)
    new_nms <- setdiff(all_nms, names(.x))
    if(is.list(.all)) {
      new_nms_in_all <- intersect(new_nms, names(.all))
      .x[new_nms] <- NA
      .x[new_nms_in_all] <- .all[new_nms_in_all]
    } else {
      .x[new_nms] <- .all
    }
    .x
  }) %>% rev()
}
```

```
library(dplyr, w = F)

mtcars %>% 
  summarize_with_margins(n =  n(), .by = quos(cyl, c(gear, cyl)))
#> # A tibble: 11 × 3
#>     gear   cyl     n
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1    NA     4    11
#>  2    NA     6     7
#>  3    NA     8    14
#>  4     3     4     1
#>  5     3     6     2
#>  6     3     8    12
#>  7     4     4     8
#>  8     4     6     4
#>  9     5     4     2
#> 10     5     6     1
#> 11     5     8     2
```