# Multiple Melts with categories and sub-categories in R

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

I have below data:

```
structure(list(Filters = structure(c(4L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 
7L), .Label = c("product type : shade || shade family : white", 
"space : bedroom || product type : appliances", "space : bedroom || shade family : white", 
"space : living room || product type : shade || shade family : white", 
"space : living room || product type : shade|appliances", "space : living room || shade family : white|black", 
"space : living room || shade family : yellows & greens"), class = "factor"), 
    Count = c(143L, 131L, 119L, 101L, 94L, 84L, 82L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I want to get sum of count for each category and subcategory available in data. also if category has multiple subcategories then each category should have sum of count for each.

For e.g. to get sum of (product type : appliances) => product type : appliances & product type : shade|appliances both are eligible.

I am looking for output like:

```
                   Category Count
1                     space   660
2              product type   469
3              shade family   522
4       space : living room   445
5      product type : shade   338
6 product type : appliances   232
7                  So on ….    ..
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify how the counts are supposed to be allocated for `shade family : white|black` and `product type : shade|appliances`?

Comment: There are multiple categories in my full data. in case of shade family white | black count = 20, then 20 should get added to shade family white and shade family black both. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is with `separate_rows` and `separate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidry)
df %>%
  separate_rows(Filters,sep = " \\|\\| ") %>%
  separate(Filters, into = c("Category","Subcategory")," : ") %>%
  group_by(Category, Subcategory) %>%
  summarise(Count = sum(Count)) %>%
  bind_rows(group_by(.,Category) %>%
              summarize(Count  = sum(Count)) %>%
              mutate(Subcategory = "Total")) %>%
  separate_rows(Subcategory,sep = "\\|") %>%
  arrange(-Count)
# A tibble: 13 x 3
# Groups:   Category [3]
   Category     Subcategory      Count
   <chr>        <chr>            <int>
 1 space        Total              660
 2 shade family Total              522
 3 product type Total              469
 4 space        living room        445
 5 shade family white              321
 6 product type shade              237
 7 space        bedroom            215
 8 product type appliances         131
 9 shade family white              119
10 shade family black              119
11 product type shade              101
12 product type appliances         101
13 shade family yellows & greens    82
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178517/13095326) from @Bishops_Guest for some inspiration.

Comment: Thank you for this. if you see row number nine in your output data. I can see "shade family white|black". this count should be included in "shade family : white" and "shade family : black". there can not be any pipes in output data. Thanks. let me know just in case.