# how to use mutate () in a data frame to calculate the row sum in R?

Tags: r, sum, dplyr

I try to use mutate to add up each row to get the sum but it doesn't work.

```
x <- cbind(x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), x2 = c(4:1, 2:5))
```

[image]

Comment: If you wanna use mutate, here is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507019/add-margin-row-totals-in-dplyr-chain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add margin row totals in dplyr chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507019/add-margin-row-totals-in-dplyr-chain)

Answer (score 0):

First, the object you're creating is a matrix and tidyverse functions like mutate only work on data.frame or tibble objects. The following code should do what you're trying to do.

The first chunk of code is the same as your original code, except instead of using cbind, each "x" is input as a column to the dataframe x.

Then in the next chunk of code, you indicate that you want to do a rowwise operation on the columns of x to make row_sum. We indicate that we the new column is "row_sum" and we want to take the sum of the columns x1 and x2.

```r
library(tidyverse)
x <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                x2 = c(4:1, 2:5))
x_row_sum <- x %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(row_sum = sum(across(x1:x2)))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>