# Add Group Subheader and Subtotal Rows to data.frame or table in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, rvest, gt

### Objective

I wish to add subheader and subtotal/margin rows within a table. Ultimately, I am looking for a structure shown below, which I will export to Excel with `openxlsx` and `writeData`.

|  | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  |  |  |
| A1 | 1001 | 1157 | 911 |
| A2 | 1005 | 803 | 1110 |
| A3 | 1125 | 897 | 1190 |
| Total A | 3131 | 2857 | 3211 |
| B |  |  |  |
| B1 | 806 | 982 | 1098 |
| B2 | 1106 | 945 | 1080 |
| B3 | 1057 | 1123 | 867 |
| Total B | 2969 | 3050 | 3045 |
| C |  |  |  |
| C1 | 847 | 1087 | 1140 |
| C2 | 1146 | 966 | 1176 |
| C3 | 1071 | 915 | 892 |
| Total C | 3064 | 2968 | 3208 |
| Total All | 9164 | 8875 | 9464 |

I suspect the subheaders and subtotals are completely different questions, but I am asking both here in case there is a common method related to each.

### Reproducible Code So Far

**Create the Sample Data (long format):**

```r
d <- data.frame(
  year = rep(c(2019, 2020, 2021), times = 9),
  sector = rep(c("A","B","C"),each = 9),
  subsector = paste0(rep(c("A","B","C"),each = 9), rep(c("1","2","3"), each = 3)),
  value = sample(800:1200, 27, replace = FALSE)
)
```

**Output:**

```r
head(d)
#>   year sector subsector value
#> 1 2019      A        A1  1001
#> 2 2020      A        A1  1157
#> 3 2021      A        A1   911
#> 4 2019      A        A2  1005
#> 5 2020      A        A2   803
#> 6 2021      A        A2  1110
```

**Format wide and add a margin (total) row:**

```r
library(janitor)
#[snip]warnings[/snip]
library(tidyverse)
#[snip]warnings[/snip]

d %>%
    group_by(year, sector, subsector) %>%
    summarise(sales = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = sales) %>%
    janitor::adorn_totals(where = "row")
```

**Output:**

```r
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'year', 'sector'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#>  sector subsector 2019 2020 2021
#>       A        A1 1001 1157  911
#>       A        A2 1005  803 1110
#>       A        A3 1125  897 1190
#>       B        B1  806  982 1098
#>       B        B2 1106  945 1080
#>       B        B3 1057 1123  867
#>       C        C1  847 1087 1140
#>       C        C2 1146  966 1176
#>       C        C3 1071  915  892
#>   Total         - 9164 8875 9464
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The `janitor` package's `adorn_totals()` function works well for adding a margin row or column for the entire set. And Sam Firke's response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49496054/3776785) hints at a solution using `tidyr::gather` but my data is in a different format. I don't want to "gather" the columns. Others in the same thread show solutions but they place all the totals at the end of the table.

I can imagine a solution where I loop through the sector factors and assemble and combine tables for each sector, but I suspect I am overthinking this and there is a simpler solution.

Is there an existing solution for this objective, or ideas on accomplishing this efficiently/universally?

*Please Note: the number of subsectors per sector will vary in the actual data (i.e., some may have only one subsector, others may have several), and there is no naming convention relating the subsector to the sector (i.e., the parent sector will not be part of the child subsectors name: rather than Sector: "**A**", Subsector: "**A**1", it might be Sector: "Manufacturing", Subsector: "Cars").*

### @akrun -- Solution!

Your answer got me 90% of the way there and your subsequent comments lead me to the remaining solution.

`gt` has a function `as_raw_html()` which, using `xml2::read_html()` and `rvest::html_table()` convert the `gt()` object to a tibble while keeping the subheaders.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(gt)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

d <- data.frame(
  year = rep(c(2019, 2020, 2021), times = 9),
  sector = rep(c("A","B","C"),each = 9),
  subsector = paste0(rep(c("A","B","C"),each = 9), rep(c("1","2","3"), each = 3)),
  value = sample(800:1200, 27, replace = FALSE)
)

d %>%
  group_by(year, sector, subsector) %>%
  summarise(sales = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = sales) %>%
  group_by(sector) %>%
  group_modify(~ .x %>% adorn_totals(where = "row")) %>%
  gt() %>% 
  gt::as_raw_html() %>% 
  xml2::read_html() %>% 
  rvest::html_table()
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#>    subsector `2019` `2020` `2021`
#>    <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#>  1 A         A      A      A     
#>  2 A1        932    1117   800   
#>  3 A2        925    1078   1090  
#>  4 A3        816    1058   1146  
#>  5 Total     2673   3253   3036  
#>  6 B         B      B      B     
#>  7 B1        862    1181   947   
#>  8 B2        1083   812    912   
#>  9 B3        1079   1130   1097  
#> 10 Total     3024   3123   2956  
#> 11 C         C      C      C     
#> 12 C1        966    895    944   
#> 13 C2        970    1147   1166  
#> 14 C3        1043   1116   826   
#> 15 Total     2979   3158   2936
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The subheader rows repeat the sector name in all columns; other than that, it looks good.

Interestingly, `rvest` also has a `read_html` function that might even reference the `xml2::read_html()` function, but it did not work in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of applying `adorn_totals` on the entire summary, use `group_modify` and then convert to `gt`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(janitor)
library(gt)
d %>%
  group_by(year, sector, subsector) %>%
  summarise(sales = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = sales) %>%
  group_by(sector) %>%
  group_modify(~ .x %>% adorn_totals(where = "row")) %>%
  
  gt()
```

-output

[image]

---

An option is also to split the column with `expss`

```
library(expss)
library(openxlsx)
out <- d %>%
  group_by(year, sector, subsector) %>%
  summarise(sales = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = sales) %>%
  group_by(sector) %>%
  group_modify(~ .x %>% adorn_totals(where = "row")) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  split_columns(columns = 1) 
wb <- createWorkbook()
sh <- addWorksheet(wb, "Tables")
xl_write(out, wb, sh)
saveWorkbook(wb, file.path(getwd(), "Documents/table1.xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Brilliant.  The subheaders only exist in the gt() output.  When I  write to Excel  `openxlsx::writeData()` there are no subheaders and the sector column remains.  Is there a way to convert the `gt()` to a data.frame or table that `openxlsx::writeData()` preserves?

Comment: @AWaddington that is a `gt` object and gt objects are either saved as `pdf, latex, png` etc. with `gtsave`.

Comment: @AWaddington if it is to save in excel, it may be better to save prior to the `gt` conversion as it is easier to manipulate the data without the subheaders.

Comment: @AWaddington you can check [here](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/gtsave.html) regarding saving gt object

Comment: Understood re: `gt()` object. Excel is a necessary part of the workflow, and I will be generating many tables at once.  I am hoping to avoid manual manipulation in Excel (like adding subheader rows). Letting `R` and `openxlsx` do all the work.  I will keep looking for a subheader solution outside of `gt()` . Your solution gets me really close, thank you!

Comment: I got excited for a moment, the `gt()` documentation on https://rdrr.io/cran/gt/man/as.data.frame.gt_tbl.html lists `as.data.frame.dt_tbl()` as a means to convert a `gt` object to a data frame but it outputs the same as I see without the gt()

Comment: @AWaddington the reason is that `gt` does the formatting on the grouping column from the `group_by(sector)` and shows the formatted output in html.  But, the data remains the same.  If you save the output as `out`.  you can check the `str(out)` which is a list format and the data is stored in `_data` which maybe the one you are getting with `as.data.frame.dt_tbl` i.e. `out$"_data"`

Comment: I think I figured it out based on your feedback. I will update my question with the solution.

Comment: @AWaddington I was able to get the output that matches almost similar format to your expected, but not exact when written in excel