# summary row of a table (sum of a column)

Tags: r, dplyr

Total brainfart, but how can I add a summary row at the bottom of a table that is the sum of all values in the column - while retaining all the other values?

Desired outcome:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  compound `2023` `2024` `2025` `2026` `2027`
  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A          211    306    427    548    631
2 B         6410   9132  12664  16187  18668
3 C         2598   3764   5250   6735   7760
4 total     9220  13202  18341  23469  27059
```

This one was created with a `bind_rows()` of the table and a summarized version of the table, but I can't image there not being a better way to do this.

Comment: `janitor::adorn_totals(mtcars)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507019/add-margin-row-totals-in-dplyr-chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use adorn_totals from Janitor package.

```
library(janitor)
compound = c("A", "B", "C")
a = c(10, 20, 30)
b = c(199, 299, 399)


data = tibble(compound, a, b)

data %>% adorn_totals("row")
```

[image: Sample Output]