# Add to a column with subcategories in r

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I would like to know how I can add a subcategory in a pivot table in r, similar to the ones I can get in excel. I have been trying to do it but I could only get the following result with the following code.

```
df <- data.frame(segment=rep(c('A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4'), each=4),
                 position=rep(c('G', 'F'), times=8),
                 values=round(runif(16, 4, 20),0))
dfa=df%>%
  group_by(segment)%>%
  summarise(total_values=sum(values))%>%{ x <- . 
  bind_rows(
    x,
    summarise(
      x ,
      across(where(is.numeric), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)),
      across(where(is.character), ~"TOTAL")
    )
  )}
```

[image]

As a result I have obtained this, to which I would like to add the subcategory to the column segment position as seen in the image on the right in excel.

Comment: What are you looking for in a "subcategory"? Do you just want a table with rows for each segment/position and total for the segment (as in the answers)? Are you looking for something that mimics the collapsing groups in Excel? Or do you want R to generate an excel spreadsheet with subcategories?

Comment: What I want is to be able to generate a table with a column added the rows by corresponding segments from another column or as I mentioned show as subcategories as generated in excel when creating a pivot table.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for, then: [Add margin row totals in dplyr chain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39507019/8366499)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could something like this:

1. We prepare the data by grouping and summarising the sum for each group.
2. We split by `segment` to
3. apply `adorn_totals` from `janitor` package with `map_df`.
4. Then we do some data wrangling to bring the data in the desired position:

```
library(tidyvere)
library(janitor)

df %>% 
  group_by(segment, position) %>% 
  summarise(values = sum(values)) %>% 
  split( .[,"segment"] ) %>%
  purrr::map_df(., janitor::adorn_totals) %>% 
  mutate(segment = ifelse(segment == "Total", lag(segment), segment)) %>% 
  group_by(segment) %>% 
  arrange(desc(values), .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(segment = ifelse(row_number()==1, segment, ""))
```

```
  segment position values
   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
 1 "A1"    -            39
 2 ""      F            20
 3 ""      G            19
 4 "B2"    -            46
 5 ""      F            31
 6 ""      G            15
 7 "C3"    -            36
 8 ""      F            19
 9 ""      G            17
10 "D4"    -            52
11 ""      G            28
12 ""      F            24
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
df1 <- df |> 
  group_by(segment, position) |> 
  summarize(tota_values = sum(values))

df |> 
  group_by(segment) |> 
  summarize(tota_values = sum(values)) |> 
  mutate(position = "") |> 
  bind_rows(df1) |> 
  arrange(segment, position) |> 
  relocate(position, .after = "segment")

# A tibble: 12 × 3
   segment position tota_values
   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
 1 A1      ""                59
 2 A1      "F"               32
 3 A1      "G"               27
 4 B2      ""                45
 5 B2      "F"               28
 6 B2      "G"               17
 7 C3      ""                46
 8 C3      "F"               21
 9 C3      "G"               25
10 D4      ""                39
11 D4      "F"               16
12 D4      "G"               23
```