# Add the total to a table in R

Tags: r, number-formatting, bind-rows

I want to create a table:

```
summary_table2 <- master_contracts %>%
  group_by(Branche) %>%
  summarise(Premium = round(sum(`Jahresbeitrag ohne Provision`))) %>%
  arrange(desc(Premium))
```

I would like to add the total:

```
total_sum2 <- master_contracts %>%
  summarise(Branche = "Total", Premium = round(sum(`Jahresbeitrag ohne Provision`)))
```

However, when I try to add the total to the table like this:

```
summary_table2 <- bind_rows(summary_table2, total_sum2)
```

I get an error message that the Premium from the summary_table2 is "character" and the premium from the total_sum2 is double so that I cannot combine the two as above.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: If you edit your question to make it reproducible (ie, add the output of `dput(master_contracts)` or `dput(summary_table2)`), you may get better, faster help. Good luck!

Comment: Try using ``janitor::adorn_totals()`` maybe? example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507019/add-margin-row-totals-in-dplyr-chain